# Create instance of Dependency Injected class in play 2.5.X

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play 2.5.X we need to use dependency injection. The following code is an example from play-documentation:

```
class HomeController @Inject() (configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }
}
```

If I define some additional helper method `getXXX` in `HomeController` and need to access it from somewhere else, how can I access this method?

What I am really interested in is how to create instance of `HomeController` so that I can use `homeControllerInstance.getXXX`.

If I try to create instance like following:

```
val homeControllerInstance = new HomeController()
```

I get error:

```
Compilation error[not enough arguments for constructor HomeController: (configuration: play.api.Configuration)HomeController
```

I tried to change `HomeController` class declaration to:

```
class HomeController @Inject(configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends Controller
```

But this gave me error:

```
classfile annotation arguments have to be supplied as named arguments
```

Can someone please explain, how can I fix this?

Comment: What is this helper method? Are you sure that controller is the best place to keep it?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking how to declare the Controller as an injectable component?

Comment: Is this for unit testing ? If this is the case, you might want to check out the guides https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice

Comment: after you marked you controller with @Inject annotation all parameters will be injected to HomeController and you can then inject HomeController itself whenever you need.

Comment: @michaJlS: This helper method creates HTTP request and send it to some URL. URL is read from application.conf.

Comment: @Nio: No, I am not asking "how to declare the Controller as an injectable component?"

Comment: I think you probably want to put this re-useable helper method in a service and then you can inject that in your controllers . In my opinion that would be the most reusable and you can keep your controllers slim/focused on what they do and delegate interaction with some external thing to another component

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `getXXX` method of your class `HomeController` from `Xyz` class using google juice, try this

```
import com.google.inject.Inject

class Xyz @Inject()(homeCon: HomeController) {
   homeCon.getXXX
}
```

Although I am not sure what your actual problem is, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the class with

```
play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf(classOf[UID])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to put a new line after the @Inject keyword so this:

`class HomeController @Inject(a :IWantThisInjected)
                            (configuration: play.api.Configuration)`

fails with that error, but moving the first set of params to the next line can fix it:

`class HomeController @Inject
                            (a :IWantThisInjected)
                            (configuration: play.api.Configuration)`